# What is the meaning of over sampling EFR32FG14 ADC?

Tags: embedded

In chapter 28 the SAR ADC is described.  It says that we  can have 12-bit sample with 1 mega samples per second.

Assuming I have set the ADC to work that way, what is the meaning of oversampling it?

It cannot produce more samples than what we set it to be.

So there are the basic settings and oversampling is the extra option on top?

What is the quality of those samples?

I know about oversampling in sigma delta converters, but what does it do in SAR?

https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/reference-manuals/efr32xg14-rm.pdf

[image]

Comment: You should remember that oversampling **will not** improve the accuracy of the ADC. It does nothing for gain, offset, or linearity errors. And, it will only reduce noise if the noise is zero mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the chip has hardware support for oversampling, filtering and decimation.

You have a real sampling rate, and you set an oversampling number.  The chip accumulates and averages the given number of samples.  You get more resolution, but a lower sampling rate.

If you set the sampling rate to 1 megasamples per second, 12 bit depth, and oversampling 16, then you would get the equivalent of 16 bit sampling and an effective sampling rate of 62.5 kilo samples per second.

There's a table on page 863 that shows the effective sampling depth for various oversampling settings:

[image]

Comment: Hello,So if initially we have 12 bit resolution and 1M sampls per second and we set OSR=16.
So by the table this OSR will give us 16bit data(by the table) and 1M/16=62.5KHz.
Thanks.